# Delete duplicates based on two columns and keep the row that has minimum value of another column

Tags: mysql

I converted discog's xml file to a MYSQL table, now I am faced with many duplicate entries of the same songs with different release years, this happens because of releases like "best of", etc.

I need a SQL query that will delete rows based on two columns 'artist' and 'track' but keep the earliest 'year'.. so the table looks like such:

```
id   | artist              | track                    | year
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1      Some Artist           Greatest Song Ever         1999
2      Some Artist           Greatest Song Ever         1985
3      Some Artist           Greatest Song Ever         2000
```

Basically I want to delete all except the one row with 'year' 1985.

From what I understand

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE discog ADD UNIQUE (artist, track);
```

this used to remove all but one, however I do not believe IGNORE works with new versions of mysql. And I do not know how to keep the MIN(year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this query to delete all duplicate entries, leaving the earliest one:

```
DELETE d
FROM discog d
JOIN discog d1 ON d1.artist = d.artist AND d1.track = d.track AND d1.year < d.year;
```

**Update**

An alternate solution which should be more efficient for really large tables is to create a copy, using a UNIQUE index on the rows to prevent duplicate insertion:

```
CREATE TABLE discog_copy (id INT, artist VARCHAR(50), track VARCHAR(50), year INT);
ALTER TABLE discog_copy ADD UNIQUE KEY (artist, track);
INSERT IGNORE INTO discog_copy SELECT * FROM discog ORDER BY year;
```

The unique key is on the **combination** of artist name and track name and so it will allow artists to have different tracks and different artists to have the same track name. Because the `SELECT` part of the query has `ORDER BY` year, it will insert the (artist,track,year) combination with the lowest year first and then other identical (artist, track) records will not be inserted due to the duplicate key.

[Demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/HHSMR76446)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you, I wish I can upvote you!

Comment: May have spoke to soon, I ran your query on a small 6 row table, to test, and it did what was expected. However, with this 54 million row table, it ran for about a day and a half, and ended, with no change in the table.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your MySQL server log file?

Comment: No, I wonder if it ended prematurely, as it was running for so long, I was checking handle INNODB_rows_deleted to see if it was working, it did not appear to be, using mysqladmin -u root -p ...... 5 | grep handle... it showed 5 rows deleted than every other time it was 0. Could the database just be too much?

Comment: It might be. The query itself is fine. Can you try selecting 10000 (say) records into a temporary table and running the query on that? Also, it would probably pay (if they don't exist already) to create indexes on artist, track and year.

Comment: 127 rows affected. (Query took 45.7615 seconds.)

Comment: Works fine, I know the query is sound, just think the table is to big to attempt this, artist, track and year have been indexed since i created the table

Comment: Well at 10000 rows in 45 seconds it would take 67.5 hours to process 54M records, obviously too long... I'll add an alternate solution to the answer

Comment: Can you try the new query? Perhaps add a `LIMIT 10000` to the `SELECT` on the `INSERT` to check the speed?

Comment: I will try it, and let you know, thank you, would this also copy rows that do not have duplicates? also the second query does not look like it determines MIN(year)

Comment: This doesnt work as needed, as I have many artists that have different tracks, and many of the same track names with different artists. So i do not think unique would work

Comment: Hi, I've corrected the query (it shouldn't have had year in the key), made some explanatory notes and added a demo of the query working on rextester.

Comment: I tested it with a limit of 10000, it flies through the data, however when I cross check it with the original database it seems to jump quite a bit of rows the first 3500 are missing, and I know some of those are NOT duplicates, it should be starting at row 1 correct?

Comment: Ahh, never mind I see because of ORDER BY year, it is starting with the lowest year

Comment: Sounds promising. Let me know how you go with the whole table.